# IE 11 keeps showing the old populated value in the text box after the value has been recalculated and should be different

Tags: kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11, kendo-ui-grid

It seems to be happening only with IE. I'm using IE 11
Chrome and Firefox are fine.

What happens is:
1. I open the Item details page that shows Item Original Amount

[image]

2. Then I click on the button that opens the pop up window, where I need to update an amount field for that item.

   [image]

   The Database has the following data before an update:

   [image]
3. I enter the amount int the text field and submit the form.

[image]

The amount is subtracted from original amount and data is updated with a new value in database.

[image]

Then, I navigate to the main page that lists all the items and I click on just updated item to open its details page. On that page the correct amount shown as in a database:
[image]

However, when opening pop up again, the controller method that gets new data is not getting hit and there is still old amount shown as $414.00 on the pop up window:
[image]

It seems to be happening only in IE.

Chrome and Firefox shows the correct amount of $314.00

This is the code that opens a Pop Up window

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Item", "OpenNewItem", "ItemDetail", new
                   {
                       itemId = Model.Item.ItemId
                   }, new { @class = "modal-link k-button k-primary", onclick = "$('#AssignedItem_validationMessage').css('display', 'none');$('#NewAmount_validationMessage').css('display', 'none')" })
```

There is an ajax request used as following when when creating a new amount:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "ItemDetail",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        LoadingElementId = "loader",
        UpdateTargetId = "Item",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        OnComplete = "handleComplete",
        OnFailure = "CheckError"

    }, new { id = "CreateItemForm" }))
{

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="Item">
                @Html.Partial("_CreateNewItem", Model)
            </div>
    </div>
}
```

I'm not sure what is happening.
Has something like that has happened to anyone and what is the fix?

Comment: What about some code?

Comment: Everything works fine as far as a logic and the code. I do not think it is a code problem.

Comment: How am I supposed to guess how do you update text fields? Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I can replicate your problem.

Comment: @gene, sounds like your modal (popup) is not being cleared of its values after you submit. So, you are still seeing the values in the popup before your submitted.

Comment: @RyanWilson But it only happens for IE. All other browsers are fine

Comment: @gene what dose the code look like that executes when you click the button to open the popup window?

Comment: I posted a code when to open popup

Comment: I found out that when opening the pop up for the second time, the controller method responsible for getting the new values and updating the model is not being hit, that's why the pop up shows old values. But it happens only in IE

Answer (score 1):

We the help of my coworker, we finally found the solution to the problem.

We needed to add `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` method into a `Global.asax.cs` file like the following:

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndNoCache);
}
```